# How to show one stacked bar and one non-stacked bar in a single bar chart in Google spreadsheets or Excel?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have 2 sets of Data from the same time period mapped to bar charts like this:

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to show both these charts on the same graph side-by-side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot one set on the primary y axis and and the other on the secondary y axis. You can assign the option to do this by opening the format box for the series.